# Add javascript to rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

I want to add a custom javascript file to a mountable rails engine (storytime gem). Is there anyway to do with without modifying the gem itself? I tried putting the javascript file into the engine javascript directory `/assets/javascripts/storytime/myscript.js` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, **When you use javascript related gem in engine it will not autoload**, I used '**jquery-ui-rails**' was not auto loading even required in application.js.

I fixed it by require in **engine.rb**

```
require 'jquery-ui-rails'
```